# Https requests to our apache server sometimes return empty response and empty header

Tags: apache, tcp, http-headers, httpresponse, apache-config

We have an API which runs on apache 2 server. Our client which makes requests to our API claims that they didn’t receive a response to their requests in some cases (especially when they submit a large number of requests in a short period of time) and they have simply received a response with an empty header and empty body. We on the other hand don’t see anything with zero length response in our access log and therefore we are wondering whether the request was received or not in the first place. Could our apache server drop/close connection in some cases because of maxkeepaliverequests or keepalive timeout settings in apache? What would they see if they reach the max keep alive limitation? Would they receive an empty response?

Comment: You will need to monitor your system (cpu, ram) and Apache (workers, avg response time, ...) while your client is "bombarding" the site to see, probably a performance issue.  Load tests!